# Javascript list view to grid view problem

Tags: javascript, dom, flexbox, dom-events

I was trying to create a simple application where we can toggle between list view to grid view. But some problem occurs as usual. If I customize the list view alone in Js then it's working fine and it looks like this-[image: list view]

But when I am trying to add grid view using flexbox and applying event listener then the grid option working fine.
Like this-

[image: grid view]

But if it toggles again then somehow list styling is being adapted into those flexboxes made for the grid.like this-

[image: problem view]

My JS code-

```js
//Assigning UI
const productRow = document.querySelector(".row");
const images = document.querySelectorAll(".image");
const productTemplate = document.querySelectorAll('.product');
const unorderedList = document.querySelectorAll('ul');
const productItems = document.querySelectorAll('.product-item');
const buyBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.buy');
const productHeading = document.querySelectorAll('h3');
const listView = document.querySelector('#list-view');
const gridView = document.querySelector('#grid-view');
const btnSection = document.querySelector('.buttons');

//Css variables
const borderShadow = '-webkit-box-shadow: -1px 0px 20px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);-moz-box-shadow: -1px 0px 20px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);box-shadow: -1px 0px 20px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);';
const mainBtn = `width:10%;height:10%;padding:2%;border:none;${borderShadow};border-radius:15px;cursor: pointer;margin-left:15px;`;

//Listen For Events
btnSection.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    let targetElement = e.target;
    if(targetElement.id === 'list-view'){
        listViewOperation();
    }else if(targetElement.id === 'grid-view'){
        gridStyleView();
    }else{
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});

//By default grid style
gridStyleView();

//universal
document.body.style.cssText ="font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;";

//remove buttes
iteration(unorderedList, "list-style-type: none;");

// //Resizing buttons
listView.style.cssText = mainBtn;
gridView.style.cssText = mainBtn;

//Iteration function
function iteration(itarator,cssElements){
    itarator.forEach(function(variable){
        variable.style.cssText = cssElements;
    });
}

function listViewOperation(){
    //list Test
    //Productlist view flex
    iteration(productTemplate, `display:flex;border:1px solid transparent;${borderShadow};margin:2% 1%;;border-radius:15px;justify-content:space-evenly;`);

    //Images
    iteration(images, "width:10%;");

    //Buybutton
    iteration(buyBtn, "width:15%;height:10%;transform:translateY(30%);");

    //Heading
    iteration(productHeading, "transform:translateY(30%);");
}

//gridview function
function gridStyleView(){
    //grid view
    productRow.style.cssText = "display:flex;";

    //For Images
    iteration(images,"width:50%;");

    //For Product Template
    iteration(productTemplate,`text-align:center;border:1px solid transparent;${borderShadow};margin:2% 1%;;border-radius:15px;justify-content:space-evenly;padding:1%;`);

    //For buy now button
    iteration(buyBtn,"width:60%;height:23%;transform:translateY(-10%);");
}
```

My HTML code

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="buttons">
            <button type="submit" value="list" id="list-view"><i class="fas fa-list"></i></button>
            <button type="submit" value="grid" id="grid-view"><i class="fas fa-th-large"></i></button>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="product">
                <img class="image product-item" src="https://store.storeimages.cdn-apple.com/4982/as-images.apple.com/is/iphone11-select-2019-family?wid=882&amp;hei=1058&amp;fmt=jpeg&amp;qlt=80&amp;op_usm=0.5,0.5&amp;.v=1567022175704" alt="Iphone11">
                <h3>Apple Iphone 11</h3>
                <ul>Description
                    <li>256 GB Storage</li>
                    <li>6Gb Ram</li>
                    <li>Wide Lense Camera</li>
                    <li>Bionic A13 Chip</li>
                    <li>Attractive EMI OFFER</li>
                    <li>Exchange For Your Kidney</li>
                </ul>
                <img class="buy" src="https://q3p9g6n2.rocketcdn.me/wp-content/ml-loads/2015/08/image091.png" alt="buynow">
            </div>
            <div class="product">
                <img class="image" src="https://store.storeimages.cdn-apple.com/4982/as-images.apple.com/is/iphone11-select-2019-family?wid=882&amp;hei=1058&amp;fmt=jpeg&amp;qlt=80&amp;op_usm=0.5,0.5&amp;.v=1567022175704" alt="Iphone11">
                <h3>Apple Iphone 11</h3>
                <ul>Description
                    <li>256 GB Storage</li>
                    <li>6Gb Ram</li>
                    <li>Wide Lense Camera</li>
                    <li>Bionic A13 Chip</li>
                    <li>Attractive EMI OFFER</li>
                    <li>Exchange For Your Kidney</li>
                </ul>
                <img class="buy" src="https://q3p9g6n2.rocketcdn.me/wp-content/ml-loads/2015/08/image091.png" alt="buynow">
            </div>
            <div class="product">
                <img class="image" src="https://store.storeimages.cdn-apple.com/4982/as-images.apple.com/is/iphone11-select-2019-family?wid=882&amp;hei=1058&amp;fmt=jpeg&amp;qlt=80&amp;op_usm=0.5,0.5&amp;.v=1567022175704" alt="Iphone11">
                <h3>Apple Iphone 11</h3>
                <ul>Description
                    <li>256 GB Storage</li>
                    <li>6Gb Ram</li>
                    <li>Wide Lense Camera</li>
                    <li>Bionic A13 Chip</li>
                    <li>Attractive EMI OFFER</li>
                    <li>Exchange For Your Kidney</li>
                </ul>
                <img class="buy" src="https://q3p9g6n2.rocketcdn.me/wp-content/ml-loads/2015/08/image091.png" alt="buynow">
            </div>
            <div class="product">
                <img class="image" src="https://store.storeimages.cdn-apple.com/4982/as-images.apple.com/is/iphone11-select-2019-family?wid=882&amp;hei=1058&amp;fmt=jpeg&amp;qlt=80&amp;op_usm=0.5,0.5&amp;.v=1567022175704" alt="Iphone11">
                <h3>Apple Iphone 11</h3>
                <ul>Description
                    <li>256 GB Storage</li>
                    <li>6Gb Ram</li>
                    <li>Wide Lense Camera</li>
                    <li>Bionic A13 Chip</li>
                    <li>Attractive EMI OFFER</li>
                    <li>Exchange For Your Kidney</li>
                </ul>
                <img class="buy" src="https://q3p9g6n2.rocketcdn.me/wp-content/ml-loads/2015/08/image091.png" alt="buynow">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

No external framework used. Any suggestion or help will be appreciated and sorry for my messy code as I have not to use CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've went through your code and found out where the problem is.
when you click on the "list view", just add "flex-direction: column;" property to the div with class=row. Below is the complete line you need to add.

```
productRow.style.cssText = "display:flex;flex-direction:column";
```

Add this to your listViewOperation function and everything will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

I am trying to understand your code with CSS or bootstrap in mind.
But you can try this:

SET FOUR (4) CLASSES,
2 to control list view for #products-container and .product and
2 to control grid view for #products-container and .product

In this case, on click of its button, you do .addClass() and .removeClass() to reflect what you want.
Try:

```
.products-container-list-view {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-column: 1fr;
}

.product-list-view {
   display: flex;
}

.products-container-grid-view {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-column: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.product-grid-view {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
}

.product {
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
}

$('#grid-view-btn').on('click', () => {
  $('#products-container').addClass('.products-container-grid-view');
  $('.product').addClass('.product-grid-view');
  $('#products-container').removeClass('.products-container-list-view');
  $('.product').removeClass('.product-list-view');
}

$('#list-view-btn').on('click', () => {
  $('#products-container').addClass('.products-container-list-view');
  $('.product').addClass('.product-list-view');
  $('#products-container').removeClass('.products-container-grid-view');
  $('.product').removeClass('.product-grid-view');
}
```

You can use media queries on these classes for responsiveness.

**Another approach:**

Put

```
<div id="products-container">
```

after your

```
<div class="row">
```

set *#product-container* to **display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;**
set each of *.product* to **display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;**

This should give you the LIST VIEW LAYOUT which should work on click of its button too.

FOR GRID VIEW:

```
$('#grid-view').on('click', () => {
  $('#products-container').css('flex-direction', 'column');
  $('.products').css('flex-direction', 'column');
}
```

Please, here you should set a width for *.product* and calculated or equal margins/paddings for them, so they align well.

Note: **I chose this method for ease with responsiveness**